# Dayton furnace blower wiring help

Tags: voltage

I bought the new Dayton 3 phase 208/230vac blower model #3HMJ8.  There is 3 wires red/white/black and next to the diagram for each wire on the blower is a letter.  I don’t know what these letters mean..  my goal is to have it hooked up to a clothes dryer cord/plug that’s 240v so I can just plug it in and use as a fan as needed..  can anyone tell me how to hook his up....  graingers instructions are horrible I emailed them no reply yet 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't hook up a 3 phase motor to a  split 1 phase supply without big phase shifting caps.  wrong motor.

Comment: If you have three phase power, which I doubt, you just connect the three wires to the three hot phase wires and the frame of the motor to ground. If the three phase power has a neutral, you don'd connect it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ftj3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is North American residential standard 240Vac split phase (120L1,120L2+N)

For bigger motors, some people buy VFD generators. 1 to 3Ph.

It is not a perfect match and supplies 240V ph-ph instead of 208~230V ph-ph rated.  It might have 50% speed since 60Hz requires more voltage than 50V motors (V/F) and the phases are not balanced.

This is my estimate of what you need.  I have not done this myself.

The cap you must buy may be used for PFC or Motor Start/run cap rated > 400Vac.  Depending on inductance of motor, determines value of 40uF cap.  Seach for better values online or measure actual motor inductance.

Answer (score 0):

On the label (bottom pic) it is clear, after the word "VOLTS" is the term "3PH".

That means the device is meant to operate on 3-phase AC power.  That's not what the normal house has installed and you cannot, therefore, easily use.

Comment: ok thanks so its pretty much useless lol.  could i use just 2 of the hot wires possibly on the  blower and cap one and get it working with less power or is this impossible as well